# Sorting a list based on a condition placed on property of its inner list

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a `List<Order>` and each `Order` has an inner list `List<Item>`, each `Item` has a property `IsLateForDelivery`. I want to sort the list of orders so that an `Order` with **most** number of `Items` that are Late for delivery is at index `0`.

Comment: Anything you've tried yet ?

Comment: mark the answer as accepted please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
Using System.Linq;
//List<Order> Orders
Orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.Items.Count(item => item.IsLateForDelivery))
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a genius ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();
        //List seed
        orders = orders.OrderByDescending(x => x.Items.Count(y => y.IsLateForDelivery)).ToList();
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public bool IsLateForDelivery { get; set; }
}
```